# How do I install DTrace?

Tags: software-installation

Googling suggests that DTrace is available on Linux but I can't find instructions as how to install it.

> DTrace is a comprehensive dynamic tracing framework. It is designed to give operational insights that allow users to tune and troubleshoot applications and the OS itself. Special consideration has been taken to make it safe to use in a production environment. For example, there is minimal probe effect when tracing is underway, and no performance impact associated with any disabled probe; this is important since there are tens of thousands of DTrace probes that can be enabled.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use git or download several versions of [dtrace here](http://crtags.blogspot.com/). I found these [Installation instructions](https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux#installation):

```
git clone "https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux.git" dtrace
cd dtrace
tools/get-deps.pl
make all 
make install
sudo make load
```

---

Sidenote:
[A comment on brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/11463) claims you could do the same with these 3:

- [pTrace](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man2/ptrace.2freebsd.html)
- [uTrace](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man2/utrace.2freebsd.html)
- [systemtap](http://packages.ubuntu.com/systemtap) [image: Install systemtap]

Comment: interesting question - this weblink says that dtrace is not available for "debian" (aka ubuntu?) - its more up-to-date than your linked instruction.  http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:a0IQlXYiVkkJ:www.jquantlib.org/index.php/Installing_DTrace_on_Debian+dtrace+debian&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=ubuntu

Comment: See the last comment on brainstorm here: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/4971 No deb but it is useable on Ubuntu.

Comment: ok - hopefully the OP will test this out - +1 from me.

Comment: I also found this one http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/11463 ptrace, utrace and systemtap edited in as an alternative (did not try these too btw ;) )

Comment: . build/config.sh ; \
mkdir -p ""/usr/lib/dtrace/$CPU_BITS ; \
rm -f ""/usr/lib/dtrace/types.d ; \
mkdir -p ""/usr/sbin/ ; \
install -m 4755 -o root build/dtrace ""/usr/sbin/dtrace ; \
install -m 644 -o root build/drti.o ""/usr/lib/dtrace/$CPU_BITS/drti.o
mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/lib/dtrace': Permission denied
install: cannot create regular file '/usr/sbin/dtrace': Permission denied
install: cannot create regular file '/usr/lib/dtrace/64/drti.o': No such file or directory
makefile:110: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1

Answer (score 19):

## 1

I found the sytemtap-sdt-dev package. From a terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install systemtap-sdt-dev
```

This package provides `dtrace`.

Please note that although it's named `dtrace` for a reason, it's not exactly the same as the original from `Solaris`. You can probably do some stuff, but not all.

## 2

If you don't mind compiling, a more feature-complete version of `dtrace` is the port by Paul Fox:
ftp://crisp.dyndns-server.com/pub/release/website/dtrace/

It's pretty easy to build, see README.

## 3

There's also an `Oracle` port. But I haven't tested it and [wouldn't recommend](http://dtrace.org/blogs/ahl/2011/10/10/oel-this-is-not-dtrace/) it. Apparently, it only has about 0,1 percent of the probes the Paul Fox port.

```
$ dtrace -l | wc -l
394267
```

Which is ironic, because `Oracle` purchased `Sun`, the original authors of `dtrace` for `Solaris`.

## 4

Note that Linux-dtrace lacks some userspace functionality that the (original) Solaris-dtrace provides. So certain uses for dtrace, such as profiling Node.js, will be complicated, if not impossible, using either clone, fork or immitation of dtrace.

Comment: Indeed, the version in "systemtap-sdt-dev" does not support the "-n" option